# Kubernetes controller-manager and api server issue

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and, trying to setup the master and 2 node architecture using oracle Virtualbox.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Docker: 17.03.2-ce
Kubernetes
Client Version: v1.17.4
Server Version: v1.17.4

When I run the join command on the worker node, "kube-controller-manager" and "api-server manager" get disappeared and worker nodes are not getting joined (though join command executed successfully)

I have set the Environment="KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs" but still same error.
Please see below snapshot.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: you have different VMs for each node?

Comment: Yes, 3 different VMs. 1 master and two workers.

Comment: add the join command

Comment: kubeadm join 192.168.56.2:6443 --token ymgzcy.sulummkat8i56sts  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:b2177be5ade798f26381007df60900ae4cd62b3ee7b5226e152d177dbd51dc56

Comment: @harpr Could you please share the guide/doc you fallowed while creating your cluster?

Comment: https://hsdevops.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

The link you have provided is no longer available. While learning and trying out Kubernetes for the first time I highly recommend using the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/).

There you will find a detailed guide regarding [Creating a single control-plane cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#troubleshooting). Note that:

> To follow this guide, you need:
>
> - One or more machines running a deb/rpm-compatible Linux OS; for example: Ubuntu or CentOS.
> - 2 GiB or more of RAM per machine–any less leaves little room for your apps.
> - At least 2 CPUs on the machine that you use as a control-plane node.
> - Full network connectivity among all machines in the cluster. You can use either a public or a private network.
>
> You also need to use a version of kubeadm that can deploy the version
>   of Kubernetes that you want to use in your new cluster.
>
> Kubernetes’ version and version skew support policy applies to kubeadm
>   as well as to Kubernetes overall. Check that policy to learn about
>   what versions of Kubernetes and kubeadm are supported. This page is
>   written for Kubernetes v1.18.
>
> The kubeadm tool’s overall feature state is General Availability (GA).
>   Some sub-features are still under active development. The
>   implementation of creating the cluster may change slightly as the tool
>   evolves, but the overall implementation should be pretty stable.

If you encounter any issues, first try the [troubleshooting steps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Issue was persisting because, I was keeping two different network in oracle VM. One "Bridged Adaptor" and another was "Host only Adaptor". Both were having different ip class. I tried to join the node with "Bridged network" IP , which helped to resolve my issue.

Comment: @harpr Thanks for the response. Consider posting your own answer or edit mine so the rest of the community could easily find it.